# slurm: srun & sbatch different performance with the same settings

Tags: shell-script, parallelism, mpi, slurm

In a slurm system, when I use **srun** command to run the program. It runs very slow and seems like only one processor works.

```
 srun --pty -A free -J test  -N 1 -n 1 -c 1  mpirun -np 16
 $FEAPHOME8_3/parfeap/feap  -log_summary lu.log
```

But if I write a **sbatch** script, it can run very quickly and looks like all the processors work.

```
#!/bin/sh -l
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --account=free
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=24
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --time=6:00:00

echo ' '
echo ' ****** START OF MAIN-JOB ******'
date

srun -n 16 echo y | mpirun -np 16 $FEAPHOME8_3/parfeap/feap -log_summary lu.log

echo ' ****** END OF MAIN-JOB ******'

#End of script
```

Could anybody please tell me what's going on?

Comment: Does it run slowly if you remove `--pty` as well?

Comment: Thanks, but the code cannot run without --pty.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters `-N 1 -n 1 -c 1`  request one single CPU on one node. Replace them with `-n 16`  and remove the `mpirun` ; the `srun` will handle the MPI startup process.